# Reset after save bug - Not restoring to correct initialValues

Tags: redux-form

I am having a very weird bug. I have reproduced the simplest test case scenario here: https://codesandbox.io/s/PNyPwyWP2

I have also uploaded a screencast explaining, the screencast is on youtube here - https://youtu.be/iILiFieO-gk

My goal is that I have a form with a single field, a button "Reset" and a button "Save". Clicking "Save" saves the form values into a reducer in my `store` called `save`. Clicking "Reset" should reset the form values to the last "pristine" values (the values in `initialValues`).

However my issue is,  after saving the form, the "Reset" button should reset it to the "pristine" value (the newly saved value, the value in initialValues) but it is reseting it to the "old pristine value"

Here is my full app code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm, reducer as form } from 'redux-form'

// ACTION & ACTION CREATOR
const SAVE_FORM = 'SAVE_FORM';
function saveForm(values) {
  return {
    type: SAVE_FORM,
    values
  }
}
// REDUCER - save
const INITIAL = { url:'hiiii' };
function save(state=INITIAL, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SAVE_FORM: return action.values;
    default: return state;
  }
}


// STORE
const reducers = combineReducers({ form, save });
const store = createStore(reducers);

// MY FORM COMPONENT
class MyFormDumb extends React.Component {
  handleReset = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.reset();
  }
  render() {
    console.log('MyFormDumb :: pristine:', this.props.pristine, 'initialValues:', this.props.initialValues);
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="url">URL</label>
        <Field name="url" component="input" type="text" />
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const MyFormControlled = reduxForm({ form:'my-form' });

const MyFormSmart = connect(
  function(state) {
    return {
      initialValues: state.save
    }
  }
);

const MyForm = MyFormSmart(MyFormControlled(MyFormDumb));

// MY APP COMPONENT
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  submitHandler = (values, dispatch, formProps) => {
    dispatch(saveForm(values));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <div className="app">
            <MyForm onSubmit={this.submitHandler} />
          </div>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

// RENDER
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use `enableReinitialize: true` flag on your reduxForm component, [as per the docs](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/examples/initializeFromState/).